# Yii Undefined property: CWebApplication::$user

Tags: php, session, yii, autologin

I have an extended version of WebUser.

It worked perfectly fine. Until today I activated "autoLogin" with a time. Now when the user comes back, and auto-login kicks in, there is an error in this method:

```
public function afterLogin($fromCookie)
    {
            parent::afterLogin($fromCookie);

            // Update Last Login
            $model = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
            $model->last_visit = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
            $model->save();
    }
```

The error is:

```
Undefined property: CWebApplication::$user
```

Does that mean that the auto-login does not create the 'user' property anymore??

If I remove those lines, the rest of the site seems to work fine so far.

```
PHP notice

Undefined property: CWebApplication::$user

/Users/nathan/Git/web/protected/components/WebUser.php(16)

04 // protected/components/WebUser.php
05  
06 class WebUser extends RWebUser {
07  
08     // Store model to not repeat query.
09     private $_model;
10         
11     public function afterLogin($fromCookie)
12     {
13             parent::afterLogin($fromCookie);
14 
15             // Update Last Login
16             $model = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
17             $model->last_visit = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
18             $model->save();
19     }
20  
21     // Return first name.
22     // access it by Yii::app()->user->first_name
23     function getDisplayName(){
24         $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
25         return $user->displayName;
26     }
27     
28     function getNotificationCount(){
Stack Trace
#0  
–  /Users/nathan/Git/web/yii/yiilite.php(4087): WebUser->afterLogin(true)
4082                     if($this->autoRenewCookie)
4083                     {
4084                         $cookie->expire=time()+$duration;
4085                         $request->getCookies()->add($cookie->name,$cookie);
4086                     }
4087                     $this->afterLogin(true);
4088                 }
4089             }
4090         }
4091     }
4092     protected function renewCookie()
#1  
–  /Users/nathan/Git/web/yii/yiilite.php(3943): CWebUser->restoreFromCookie()
3938     public function init()
3939     {
3940         parent::init();
3941         Yii::app()->getSession()->open();
3942         if($this->getIsGuest() && $this->allowAutoLogin)
3943             $this->restoreFromCookie();
3944         elseif($this->autoRenewCookie && $this->allowAutoLogin)
3945             $this->renewCookie();
3946         if($this->autoUpdateFlash)
3947             $this->updateFlash();
3948         $this->updateAuthStatus();
#2  
–  /Users/nathan/Git/web/yii/yiilite.php(1050): CWebUser->init()
1045             $config=$this->_componentConfig[$id];
1046             if(!isset($config['enabled']) || $config['enabled'])
1047             {
1048                 unset($config['enabled']);
1049                 $component=Yii::createComponent($config);
1050                 $component->init();
1051                 return $this->_components[$id]=$component;
1052             }
1053         }
1054     }
1055     public function setComponent($id,$component,$merge=true)
#3  
–  /Users/nathan/Git/web/yii/yiilite.php(905): CModule->getComponent("user")
900         $this->init();
901     }
902     public function __get($name)
903     {
904         if($this->hasComponent($name))
905             return $this->getComponent($name);
906         else
907             return parent::__get($name);
908     }
909     public function __isset($name)
910     {
#4  
–  /Users/nathan/Git/web/protected/controllers/SiteController.php(30): CModule->__get("user")
25      * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
26      * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
27      */
28     public function actionIndex()
29     {
30         if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccessOrDeny('readHome')){
31                     //URLs to show in the list
32                     $criteria = Yii::app()->params['currentCommunity']->getUrls();
33                     $criteria->limit = 10;
34                     $urls = Url::model()->findAll($criteria);
35
```

Comment: what is full trace stack?

Comment: I suppose that if you are a guest Yii::app()->user could not exists.

Comment: @Stefano  yii/yiilite.php(3943): CWebUser->restoreFromCookie(), then yii/yiilite.php(4087): WebUser->afterLogin(true)

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili if it's inside "afterLogin", shouldn't I be logged in already? Plus like I said, it only happens when restoring session from cookie, not when doing a regular login...

Comment: the full trace stack would be helpfull

Comment: the stack trace has a nice GUI with expandable stuff and all. I'm trying to find a way to copy it here. . . . . done!

Comment: Try replacing `Yii::app()->user->id` with `$this->id`. You are trying to call the user component from within the user component.

Comment: @WillemRenzema this seems to work! Post it as an answer with additional info if you can, so i can approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Yii::app()->user->id`, the `user` part is a instance of the `CWebUser` class (or a child of that class).

When the application loads, it tries to initialize that `user` component, and as part of that initialization, it logs in a user, and then calls  your overridden `afterLogin` method. Your `afterLogin` method in turn tries to call the component... but it hasn't finished initializing yet. So rather than get stuck in an infinite loop, Yii just tells you that the `user` component doesn't exist.

Fortunately, during the login process, a call to `changeIdentity` is made, which calls `setId`, which populates the `$id` attribute of the `user` component. This `id` attribute is in fact exactly the same attribute that is called with `Yii::app()->user->id`, only it is accessed within the object, instead of externally.